# Will Mordin speed up construction of the Crucible?

Tags: mass-effect-3

I'm stuck as to whether to convince Mordin to lie and go work on the Crucible (the sentimental choice, as Mordin is awesome), or to have him disperse the cure at the expense of his own life (the "doing right by the krogan" choice). My question is, does getting him to lie help with the Crucible at all (in terms of Galactic Readiness and all that) or is it mostly window dressing?

As I understand it, having the krogan on your side as opposed to the salarian forces you get by doing things the dalatrass' way counts for more in terms of war resources. I just want to know whether having Mordin on the Crucible contributes substantially to that or if his efforts are better served curing the genophage instead. Is it worth screwing Wrex over if Mordin gets the Crucible done? I have a feeling I know the answer, but additional input would be nice.

Answer (score 4):

Mordin does count as a war asset.

However, Wrex is not an idiot, so if he's the leader of the Krogan (instead of Wreav), you're merely delaying the inevitable - there will be a confrontation, and one of the two will die. At the end of the day, the net benefit to war assets is in Wrex's favor - the Salrian fleet just isn't worth that much, and can be recruited in a later mission if you can save the Dalatrass when she's threatened.

Now, if **Wreav** is in charge instead, you've already missed out on most of the benefits Wrex brings to the table - at this point, the net War Assets benefit probably comes from having Mordin lie. Unlike Wrex, Wreav **is** an idiot and will believe what you tell him, so you really don't have much to lose by going this route.

Answer (score 1):

The speed at which the Crucible is constructed is fixed. When you have completed (nearly) all of the priority missions it will be completed. So no, Mordin has no impact on the speed of the Crucible.

Galactic readiness is purely achieved through multiplayer and not any events in singleplayer. So no, Mordin will have no effect on galactic readiness.

The decision is purely for war assets, and if you like having Mordin around.